# Gas line in closet

Tags: natural-gas

Have a question and concern.

We are buying a new home. The V.A. appraiser has not done the appraisal yet. We have a concern and it does not look code-compliant to me and we do not know if the sellers will correct it. This house was a floor up remodel. This is a split level home. No crawl space and, due to the high ceilings, there is only attic space above the kitchen and the furnace is placed in there, really no room for anything else. The house is in Ohio. The master bedroom closet has a gas line coming through the wall. Approx 7 inches off the floor and probably 6 plus inches from the back wall and runs the length of the closet. Where it is coming through the wall directly underneath the new carpet was bulged up, I pulled it back and there was a old gas line that used to come up through the floor there. It has been cut off but not capped and isn't even flush or below the floor. The gas line going through the closet is not supported and is in a really bad spot. Is there a code on something like this and does it sound like it would pass?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the gas line made from? Black iron? CSST? And if it's cut off but not capped, is there a shutoff valve at the other end that's keeping the gas put, or what *is* it hooked to at the other end?

Comment: There is a lot of information here that is irrelevant to the actual question.  Suggest you get rid of the extra info.  Post pics of the gas line.  If it's cut off, and you don't smell gas, it's likely just a dead pipe at this point.

Comment: I known the cut off line is dead. My concearn is if the gas line sticking out of the bottom of the wall like that is code.

Comment: @Veteran -- that depends on what it's made from...